# Error creating table (#1064 - YOU have an error in your sql syntax)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just trying to create a table `persons` with some fields but I got this error `#1064 - YOU have an error in your sql syntax` Here's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE `persons`(
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`firstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
`lastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
`gender` enum('male','female') DEFAULT NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NOT NULL,
`dob` date DEFAULT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can you spotted what's wrong with my query? thank you.

Comment: Leave out the `DEFAULT` keywords.

Comment: @imant all of them? why?

Comment: like @imant said just remove the word `DEFAULT` correct syntax is `firstName varchar(100)  NOT NULL`  etc...

Comment: Because it violates the syntax. You can't have `DEFAULT NOT NULL`. It's either NULL by or not. Syntax is `NOT NULL` if you don't want nulls, and then in `DEFAULT` clause you define what's the default value if none is provided. `firstName varchar(100) NOT NULL` is what you're after.

Comment: @bnrfly I've formulated it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `persons`(
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`firstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`gender` enum('male','female') NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`dob` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can simply leave out `DEFAULT` in your attribute definitions, since you are not setting a default value and are not allowing `NULL` values anyway.